# Trying to get 2 values from 2 different spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys I am trying to get 2 values on click from 2 different span. I have several tables that have betslip and bet number odds on it, and what I just want to do is to get the name and bet odds and store it to a variable in jquery then I'll push it to a betslip. my only problem is I can't seem to get the correct values. Here's the HTML:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" id="bet">
        <span id="betslip">Lautoka FC</span> 
        <span id="betnum"> 5/6</span>
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="#" id="bet">
        <span id="betslip">Draw</span>
        <span id="betnum">11/5</span>
    </a>
 </td>
```

Here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#betslip, #betnum').click(function() {
    var bet = $(this).text();
    var num = $(this).text();
    alert("name: " + bet + "num: " + num);
    });


});
```

I'm getting the wrong values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what values you get?

Comment: `var bet = $(this).text();
    var num = $(this).text();`  both values would be same...

Comment: same value, if I click Lautoka FC both values will be shown as Lautoka FC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` will refer the element that is clicked. You may need to select element again if you need both the values. You may use classes if scenario of multiple combination comes in.

Example Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bet').click(function() {
    var bet = $(this).find(".betslip").text();
    var num = $(this).find(".betnum").text();
    console.log("name: " + bet + " num: " + num);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <a href="#" class="bet">
    <span class="betslip">Lautoka FC</span> 
    <span class="betnum"> 5/6</span>
  </a>
</td>
<td>
  <a href="#" class="bet">
    <span class="betslip">Draw</span>
    <span class="betnum">11/5</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: But what if I have several spans? I mean, i have other spans that will use betslip id and betnum id

Comment: id should be unique on a HTML document. Even if you give same id to multiple elements it mostly returns the first element and not all. class name would fit your requirment

Comment: Can you suggest what I should do?

Comment: Could you please share the exact use case.

Comment: @TheTruth : When you click particular span you just need that combination of bet and odds or all in the table at that moment.?

Comment: I just need the particular bet and odd..

if I click on this:
    <a href="#" id="bet">
        <span id="betslip">Lautoka FC</span> 
        <span id="betnum"> 5/6</span>
    </a>

I just need to get Lautoka FC 5/6 and store it in 2 diff variables

Comment: @TheTruth : Updated the answer see if it suites you

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#betslip, #betnum').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        if(id == "betslip"){
            var bet = $(this).text();
            var num = $("#betnum").text();
        }else{
            var bet = $("#betslip").text();
            var num = $(this).text();
        }
        alert("name: " + bet + "num: " + num);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like .At the time of click on single `element` only passing .Not with two element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#betslip, #betnum').click(function() {
    var bet = $('#betslip').text();
    var num = $('#betnum').text();
    alert("name: " + bet + "num: " + num);
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><a href="#" id="bet">
  <span id="betslip">Lautoka FC</span> <span id="betnum"> 5/6</span></a></td>
```